# CodeSign certificate at runtime is different than the one with an archived app

Tags: xcode, codesign, code-signing-certificate, macos-sonoma

On my macOS app, compiled on XCode 15.0 and Sonoma 14.0, I use the `SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath` and `SecCodeCopySigningInformation` to get a `NSDictionary` containing several information about the app. The key @"certificates" returns 3 certificates.

When I compile and run the app with XCode the first certificate returns my development name and ID as (1)

**Apple Development: Leonardo BlaBla (FD6FSCR…)**

When I archive, notarise and launch the app, it returns the Developer ID Application name and ID as (2)

**Developer ID Application: Leonardo BlaBla (4XANZGGC…)**

So, since they are two different developer IDs, how can I check those?
Do I miss some certificate? Should I check the certificate when archived only?
Is a way to always get the second data?